# Can I have multiple archive-manager-enabled deployers sharing the same archive manager database?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, deployer, archival, archive-manager-1-sp3

I am in the process of setting up Archive Manager and I managed to get it to work, both for the "archive" (deployer) and the "explore" (CM Side). I have dedicated deployers for mutltiple sites and some of them have archive manager configured. **What is the best practice regarding archives segregation? Should I have dedicated databases for for each archive-manager-enabled-deployer?**

From a requirement perspective it would be ok (as long as it works and there's no conflict) to have all the archive data for different sites in the same archive manager db.

**What if two publications are used to serve pages for the same domain?** I have a publication I am using to migrate certain pages (eventually all pages will migrate to this publication) so within the same domain I could have:

1. www.mydomain.com/pages/page1.html
2. www.mydomain.com/pages/page2.html

Where page1 comes from publication A and page2 comes from publication B. Each publication has its own publication target and dedicated deployer, however I would like to share the same archive manager db.

Any thoughs?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that SDL best practice recommend a 1:1 relationship between deployer to publication. In your scenario, it maps a specific deployer to a specific publication, so you should be ok. In your single archived database, having the same domain should never have a conflict since the page is referenced in a different publications. Well, this is my 2 cents. Let's see if anyone else have different opinion about it.